# Select non-null column in FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following tables:

```
Id     |   Name     |   Family
1      |   name1    |   family1
2      |   name2    |   family2
```

And:

```
Id     |   Orderr   |   Countt
1      |   order1   |   17
1      |   order2   |   18
3      |   order3   |   16
```

And the following query:

```
select table1.id,table1.name,table1.family,table2.orderr,table2.countt
from table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2
on table1.id = table2.id
```

It returns:

```
Id     |   Name     |   Family    |   Orderr   |   Countt
1      |   name1    |   family1   |   order1   |    17
1      |   name1    |   family1   |   order2   |    18
2      |   name2    |   family2   |   NULL     |    NULL
NULL   |   NULL     |   NULL      |   order3   |    16
```

As you see in the last row it doesn't show the Id column. How can I change my query to return the Id column in the last row? I don't want to include `table2.id` in my select query because in this way I will have tow Id column.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use COALESCE or ISNULL

> COALESCE "returns the first
>   non-null expression among its arguments," and ISNULL "replaces NULL
>   with the specified replacement value."

Analysis in details at http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

```
SELECT ISNULL(table1.id, table2.id) AS id,
table1.name,table1.family,table2.orderr,table2.countt
FROM table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
```

OR

```
SELECT COALESCE(table1.id, table2.id) AS id,
table1.name,table1.family,table2.orderr,table2.countt
FROM table1 FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain a bit about ISNULL? Because based on it's name it should return if it is null.

Comment: I added a sumary but you should read the article in details if you want full insights. But in your case both works.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`coalesce`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

```
select coalesce(table1.id, table2.id) as id
```

It returns the first non-null value in the list.